# Deffinition of the current through capacitor

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

I have seen the deffinition that a current through a capacitor can be define as $c\frac{dv}{dt}$ where $c$ is the capacitance. where is this formula came from? what is its derivation?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include a link to [Capacitor: Current - voltage relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Current%E2%80%93voltage_relation) and an explanation of what remains unclear to you?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Ok now I understood what was wrong in my derivation. thank for the link

Comment: but I just do not understand what does it mean? because there is no current between the capacitor plates according to my understanding.

Comment: There is no DC, but there is AC current through the capacitor.

Comment: @my2cts, why can't there be a constant current through a capacitor (in the ideal circuit element context)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of capacitance is $$C=\frac qV$$ where $q$ is the charge on each plate ($+q$ on one and $-q$ on the other), and $V$ is the magnitude of the potential difference between the two plates.

$C$ is typically constant for a given capacitor. Therefore, we can express the amount of charge on a plate of the capacitor as $$q=CV$$ and then take a time derivative of both sides
$$\frac{\text dq}{\text dt}=C\frac{\text dV}{\text dt}$$

i.e. the rate of change of charge on the capacitor is proportional to the rate of change of the potential difference across the capacitor.

Now, this $\text dq/\text dt$ is the rate of charge being put on / taken off the capacitor, and this is what we mean by "the current through the capacitor". Of course, there isn't actually charge flowing through the capacitor from one plate to the other, but if you were do put the capacitor in a "black box", you would just see charge flowing into / out of the box as if there is current flowing through the box. This is the current you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

> but I just do not understand what does it mean? because there is no
> current between the capacitor plates according to my understanding

It's true that (ideally) no electric charge flows between the plates of a charging or discharging capacitor.

And, as the accepted answer by BioPhysicist points out (at this time), it's also true that the flow of charge *onto* one plate of a capacitor equals the flow of charge *off of* the other plate. So, looking at the capacitor from the two-terminal circuit element perspective, the current variable $i_C(t)$ is the (electric) current *through* the circuit element.

But I don't think it's entirely correct so say that "there is no current between the capacitor plates". Indeed, there *is* a current between the plates but it isn't a flow of electric charge.

The current through the region between the plates of a charging/discharging capacitor is called [displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current#Current_in_capacitors). From the linked Wikipedia article:

> An example illustrating the need for the displacement current arises
> in connection with capacitors with no medium between the plates.
> Consider the charging capacitor in the figure. The capacitor is in a
> circuit that causes equal and opposite charges to appear on the left
> plate and the right plate, charging the capacitor and increasing the
> electric field between its plates. No actual charge is transported
> through the vacuum between its plates. Nonetheless, a magnetic field
> exists between the plates as though a current were present there as
> well. One explanation is that a displacement current $I_D$ "flows" in the
> vacuum, and this current produces the magnetic field in the region
> between the plates

[image]